# MySqLi not working for some reason

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Actually I am trying to use MySqli but its is not working for me even it is showing that database is connected but query is not working even not giving any error. I tried using the code bellow:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);


    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost",'dbu', 'password');
    if($connect){
    echo 'connected';   
    }
    else {
    echo 'Failed:'.mysqli_error();  
    }
    mysqli_select_db('dbname',$connect);

    if($query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM `users`")){
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    echo $id = $fetch['id'];
    }
    }
    else {
    echo 'error:'.mysqli_error();   
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean it's not working. You just said query works and database is connected

Comment: Sorry I mean database connected but query is not working.. That was typo I fixed in the question too.

Comment: Try  mysqli_connect( "127.0.0.1", "dbu", "password", "dbname"); and remove mysqli_select_db()

Comment: If you do a `die(var_dump($num))` right after `$num = mysqli_num_rows($query);` what do you get?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get MySQLi error information in different environments? / mysqli\_fetch\_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli\_result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/how-to-get-mysqli-error-information-in-different-environments-mysqli-fetch-as)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn error on you have errors in `mysqli_*` functions. change your code to

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", 'dbu', 'password');
if ($connect) {
    echo 'connected';
} else {
    echo 'Failed:'.mysqli_connect_error();
}
mysqli_select_db($connect, 'dbname'); // <-------change this

if ($query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `users`")) { //<---------------change this
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    while ($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo $id = $fetch['id'];
    }
} else {
    echo 'error:'.mysqli_error($connect);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It fixed my problem.

Comment: every time we need to send connection id. if you used  $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','dbu','password','dbname');  as object then does not required  to  add every time please check my answer as well

Comment: @Abhijit its own choice either use `procedural way ` or `object-oriented way`

Comment: @B. Desai : object-oriented way is most preferred way. php support oop then why use procedural  way

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue with how you select the database. First parameter is the link while second is the name

```
mysqli_select_db($connect, 'db_name');
```

Alternatively you could pass the database as the fourth parameter as

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost",'dbu', 'password','db_name');
```

Also the same issue is with the query

```
mysqli_query($connect, $query);//the first parameter is the link while second is the query itself 

$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `users`");
```

Where $query is the query itself. Also do not forget to use prepared statements when you have where clauses for where statements and also when you have insert values as well as delete

Answer (score 0):

please check `mysqli_query` syntax before start to write code
https://www.w3schools.com/PhP/func_mysqli_query.asp

Your select query having syntax problem, Please change like below,

```
$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `users`") //connection paramter missing
```

May this will help

Answer (score 0):

```
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    //Open a new connection to the MySQL server

    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','dbu','password','dbname');

    //Output any connection error
    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
    }

    //MySqli Select Query
    $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users");

    while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["id"];
    }  


    // Frees the memory associated with a result
    $results->free();

    // close connection 
    $mysqli->close();
```

---

It's  Work for me please check

Comment: @SimulationCode : please try this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this.

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Order of your method pparameters are wrong
Try this

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

        $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost",'dbu', 'password');
        if($connect){
            echo 'connected';
        }
        else {
            echo 'Failed:'.mysqli_error($connect);
        }
        mysqli_select_db($connect,'dbname');

        if($query = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM `users`")){
            $num = mysqli_num_rows($query);
            while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                echo $id = $fetch['id'];
            }
        }
        else {
            echo 'error:'.mysqli_error($connect);
        }
```